# What is the duration of grief or mourning for a death in Islam and when it starts?

Tags: fiqh, death, funeral

If I remember well -correct me if I'm wrong- usually the duration for a the grief or mourning for a death person in Islam is of three days.

Now if a Muslim died in a non-Muslim country where the death body is not allowed to be buried unless the legal paperwork is done which takes 1-2 days and then the family must find an adequate graveyard where Muslims are buried. It might already take 3 or 4 days (and even more if the person for example died in the weekend) for all of this ... this made me wonder if the grief or mourning for the wife (wives) and female relatives starts with the death of the person or with the burial?

So my question is: How long is the per Islam prescribed grief for a death relative and when does this grief actually starts?

Comment: You should know that grief or better mourning is for women only and the duration depends on whether they are relatives or wives.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I know there are narrations, but I also wonder why Prophet Jacob cried for the disappearance of Prophet Yusuf for years. He cried so much that he went blind.

Comment: @Honey he is a father who is in grief for his lost son and he got revelation he first doubted then knew that his son is alive. But Allah knows best. While in case of known death the matter may be different. Allah the almighty says:" indeed, assumption avails not against the truth at all." in (10:36) and 53:28)